# rails - Create new job within a delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, recursion, delayed-job

I am creating a delayed job in my controller using the delay method as below:

```
JobProcessor.delay(:run_at => Time.now).process_job(options)
```

Now inside the process_job method I am doing

```
chunks = options[:collection].each_splice(10).to_a
chunks.each do |chunk|
  self.delay(:run_at => Time.now).chunk_job
end
```

This is giving me error `stack level too deep` when I send request to the URL

What might be the issue? Please help.

Comment: What happens when you try to run the code without the call to delay?  I imagine you probably get the same 'stack level too deep' error, which typically means you have an infinite loop somewhere in your code.  It's difficult to give further specific insight without additional context.  I'd open up the console and dive into the chunks assignment...(does it do what you expect it to do?)  Also, teh problem could be happening with the chunk_job method.

Comment: I made some changes and it worked for me. @AngeloChrysoulakis there wasn't an infinite loop present in the code, because it was working without the `delay` call. I wasn't able to figure out what the actual issue was, but its working for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work for me by doing some changes.

- I changed the outer method `process_job` to be an instance method
- And kept the rest of the code as it is.

So now my code looks like

```
JobProcessor.new.process_job(options)
```

in the controller, and inside the `JobProcessor` class I have

```
class JobProcessor
  def process_job(options)
    chunks = options[:collection].each_splice(10).to_a
    chunks.each do |chunk|
      self.class.delay(:run_at => Time.now).chunk_job(options)
    end
  end
  handle_asynchronously :process_job, :run_at => Proc.new { 2.seconds.from_now }

  def self.chunk_job(options)
    # perform chunk job here
  end
end
```

This works for me.